# How can I use a US 120 volt Ryobi charger From a 220 volt main?

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, adapter, current-transformer

I bought a ryobi kit in the us and I want to use it in in Europe.

I doubt that I can plug it directly into the socket, what kind of converter/adapter do I need?

Is there a way to adapt the charger itself?

Comment: Does it not say what input voltage range it accepts on the tag? Many SMPS these days accept all voltages between approx. 100 and 240V.

Comment: @Unimportant it says 120 volt

Answer (score 1):

Two options,

one: get a 220v to 110v transformer (usually large yellow things),

Two, purchase a Ryobi charger in EU that matches the batteries.

Comment: sorry, added to question before I saw your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just buy an off-the-shelf transformer to step down the voltage.  Make sure the wattage is not less than the wattage of the battery charger.  Smaller ones can even come with the correct US socket.